# Nestjs control over errors

Tags: nestjs

I'm processing a CSV file that's converted into JSON to make followup API calls. What is causing me a lot of pain is that I can't control the error returned, if it isn't 2xx then an error is thrown and stops the process.
what I would like to do is something like this:

```js
for await(const user of users) {
  const res = await lastValueFrom(this.httpService.post<T>('example.com/create', body).pipe(map(res) => res.data))
  if (res.status === 201 || res.status === 422) continue
  else thrown new Error(res.data)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an axios configuration. The `validateStatus` method of the [request  configuration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#request-config) can be used to customize what should happen on different error codes. In your case, it would look something like

```js
for await(const user of users) {
  const res = await lastValueFrom(
    this.httpService.post<T>(
      'example.com/create',
      body,
      {
        // customize this as you want, or return true for always resolving the promise
        validateStatus: (status) => true 
      }
    ).pipe(map(res) => res.data)
  )
  if (res.status === 201 || res.status === 422) continue
  else thrown new Error(res.data)
}
```

Do note that if you use the `map` operator as you currently are then `res.status` will not be data you can actually get to, because you assign `res` to the axios response's `data` property

Comment: thank you very much! you're a huge time saver!